# SqlCommand.ExecuteReader became very slow

Tags: sql-server

I am using this code, to call an SQL function, which returns entries from an SQL Server database table

```
string cmd = String.Format("select * from dbo.GetData(@userId, @fileId, @created);");

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", DBNull.Value);
    else
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileId))
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileId", DBNull.Value);
    else
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileId", docId);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@created", created);

    internalWatch.Reset();
    internalWatch.Start();

    IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();                
    table = GetDataTableFromDataReader(reader);

    reader.Close();
    reader.Dispose();

    conn.Close();

    internalWatch.Stop();
```

The table I am working with contains a bit more than 1.5 million entries and should return a bit more than 250k entries.

If I am executing the SQL function within SSMS it needs 8 seconds to return the results and I already used the code above last week to get the results within my desktop application. At this time everything was fine. The code needed between 10-12 seconds to get the results.

The strange thing is, that today the code needs more than 40 seconds to return the same results, but I haven't change anything within the SQL function or the code itself. The only change I did in my programm is adding a few more classes, which have nothing to do with the code above.

If I am debugging the code, I can see, that the line

```
IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

needs the most of the time now.

Since I haven't change anything in the SQL function or the code itself, I can't understand why it is taking so long now...

And if needed, here is the SQL function, I am using:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetData]
(@userId varchar(128) = NULL, 
 @fileId varchar(192) = NULL, 
 @created DateTimeOffset(7))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
    RETURN (
        WITH FindNewestVersion AS
        (
            SELECT
                *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITINO BY FileId, UserId 
                                   ORDER BY created DESC) rn 
            FROM
                table1
        )
        SELECT        
            q.Created, q.Updated, q.FileId, q.UserId, 
            F.column1, F.column2, F.column3
        FROM            
            table2 AS F 
        INNER JOIN
            table1 AS q ON F.column4 = q.PersonId AND F.created = q.created
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT 
                 created, PersonId, DocumentId 
             FROM
                 FindNewestVersion 
             WHERE
                 rn = 1) AS x ON q.created = x.created 
                              AND q.PersonId = x.PersonId 
                              AND q.FileId = x.FileId

        WHERE        
            (F.column1 = 'Sample') 
            AND (q.Created <= @created) 
            AND (q.Updated >= @created)
            AND Q.PersonId = ISNULL(@userId, Q.PersonId)
            AND Q.FileId = ISNULL(@fileId, Q.FileId)
)
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: This sounds like parameter sniffing. If the input parameter UserId is null, will the fileID parameter also be null?

Comment: No, they are seperated from each other. So it is possible, that the userId is null, while the fileId has a value and vice versa. The only parameter, which will always require a value is created.

Comment: Did the execution-time in SSMS degrade as well?

Comment: I can't really tell, because I don't remember the time it took in SSMS before. It took also a few seconds to get the results in SSMS before, but I can't tell the time exactly. It is possible, that it is also slower in SSMS now. But if it is slower now, than it didn't become this much slower than before.

Comment: read execution plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a case of parameter sniffing

One thing that you could do is rewrite your procedure as follows:

`

```
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[GetData]
CREATE PROCEDURE[dbo].[GetData]

(
@userId varchar(128) = NULL, 
@fileId varchar(192) = NULL, 
@created DateTimeOffset(7)
)

RETURNS TABLE 
AS
DECLARE @l_userId varchar(128) = NULL, 
DECLARE @l_fileId varchar(192) = NULL, 
DECLARE @l_created DateTimeOffset(7)

SET @l_userId = userId
SET @l_fileId = fileId
SET @l_created = @created



(

WITH FindNewestVersion as
(
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER() 
    over (partition by FileId, UserId ORDER BY created DESC)rn from table1
)


SELECT        q.Created, q.Updated, q.FileId, q.UserId, 
              F.column1, F.column2, F.column3
FROM            table2 AS F INNER JOIN
                table1 AS q
                ON F.column4 = q.PersonId AND F.created = q.created
                INNER JOIN
                (
                    select created, PersonId, DocumentId from FindNewestVersion where rn = 1
                ) AS x ON q.created = x.created AND q.PersonId = x.PersonId AND q.FileId = x.FileId

WHERE        (F.column1 = 'Sample') AND (q.Created <= @created) AND (q.Updated >= @created)
And Q.PersonId = ISNULL(@l_userId, Q.PersonId)
And Q.FileId = ISNULL(@l_fileId, Q.FileId)
)
```

`
You can then get you data as you would by calling a stored procedure.

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is correct? I can't use 'DECLARE' and 'SET' as you did. It tells me, that it expects a 'BEGIN_CS' or 'RETURN' after 'RETURNS TABLE AS' And also it doesn't know the parameter at this point

Comment: I have converted it to a stored procedure. You will need to modify your C# to call this correctly

Comment: This worked for me now. I can't really understand why this can make such a difference, but the execution-time is better now. In fact as a stored procedure (or with the declaration; I don't know) it is even a bit faster than ever before. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) You can find out more about parameter sniffing at the following links: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/ , https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/ , https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case of SET ARITHABORT ON

By default in SQL it's On But while we execute Through C# Code then its not understand the ARITHABORT ON.

One thing that you could do is rewrite your procedure as follows:

```
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[GetData]
CREATE PROCEDURE[dbo].[GetData]

(
@userId varchar(128) = NULL, 
@fileId varchar(192) = NULL, 
@created DateTimeOffset(7)
)

RETURNS TABLE 
AS

SET ARITHABORT ON 

DECLARE @l_userId varchar(128) = NULL, 
DECLARE @l_fileId varchar(192) = NULL, 
DECLARE @l_created DateTimeOffset(7)

SET @l_userId = userId
SET @l_fileId = fileId
SET @l_created = @created



(

WITH FindNewestVersion as
(
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER() 
    over (partition by FileId, UserId ORDER BY created DESC)rn from table1
)


SELECT        q.Created, q.Updated, q.FileId, q.UserId, 
              F.column1, F.column2, F.column3
FROM            table2 AS F INNER JOIN
                table1 AS q
                ON F.column4 = q.PersonId AND F.created = q.created
                INNER JOIN
                (
                    select created, PersonId, DocumentId from FindNewestVersion where rn = 1
                ) AS x ON q.created = x.created AND q.PersonId = x.PersonId AND q.FileId = x.FileId

WHERE        (F.column1 = 'Sample') AND (q.Created <= @created) AND (q.Updated >= @created)
And Q.PersonId = ISNULL(@l_userId, Q.PersonId)
And Q.FileId = ISNULL(@l_fileId, Q.FileId)
)`enter code here`
```